# create Mysql structure programatically from Java

Tags: java, java-native-interface

I do use Runtime class

```
    public void createDBStructure() throws IOException {
    InputStream stream = DBStructureCreator.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("sql_structure");
    if (stream == null) {
        logger.log(Level.INFO, "File copy error: sql_structure is not found.");
    } else {
        String query;
        query = StreamConverter.convertStreamToString(stream);
        String cmd = "mysql -uroot -ppassw0rd";
        Runtime run = Runtime.getRuntime();
        Process pr = run.exec(cmd);
        BufferedWriter buf = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(pr.getOutputStream()));
        buf.write(query);
        buf.write(";\n\n\n");
        buf.write("exit\n\n\n");
        buf.flush();
        buf.close();
    }
}
```

But it takes time to finish this task, still it does not block. And If I run some code imediately after tables may not be available yet.
How to make it block until mysql is done creating tables.
Either how to make it faster

Answer (score 1):

pr.waitfor() would wait until the process referenced by this Process instance completes.